# EF6 & MySql - Avoid selecting Id after inserting record

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I have a program that inserts thousands of records in a MySql DB.  The operation cannot be done in bulk for a variety of reasons.  Overall, the operations are very slow.

After looking at the SQL that is being generated, I can see that EF is calling a select to get the Id of the recently inserted record.

```
        SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ANSI'; INSERT INTO `table`(
        'blah') VALUES(
        86613784);
        SELECT
        `id`
        FROM `table`
         WHERE row_count() > 0 AND `id`= last_insert_id()
```

Since I don't need that Id, how can I tell EF to avoid the call and save me the time?

FYI - I am already using the following statements to speed things up as well.

```
        Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
        Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

As requested, here is the code used to create the record.  Not much to it, but if it helps...

```
        using (var ctx = new Tc_TrademarkEntities(_entityFrameworkConnectionString))
        {
            ctx.case_file.Add(request.Trademark);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: it would be more helpful if you show your LINQ query and client code  because that's what translated to mysql query as you posted.

Comment: Code added to show how record was inserted...